# Android: Issue in Moving View more than IME height in WindowInsetsAnimationCompat.Callback -> onProgress

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-animation

I'm trying to move `View` above the IME using `WindowInsetsAnimationCompat.Callback` API, in `onProgress` method i added `mView.setTranslationY(-(imeHeight + (100 * interpolatedFraction)))`.

I expected to move the View by `1092 /** ime height */ + 100 /** extra height */`, and `interpolatedFraction` is to equal 1 by end of the animation

The actual result is `1084 /** ime height */ + 92 /** extra height */`, `interpolatedFraction` is equal 0.92 by end of the animation

I noticed that i can't move the View more than IME height, every time i'm trying to add extra height the imeHeight and interpolatedFraction reduced by some percentage.

```
public class RootViewDeferringInsetsHandler extends WindowInsetsAnimationCompat.Callback implements OnApplyWindowInsetsListener {
  private final ThemedReactContext mContext;
  private final KeyboardMovingViewView mView;

  public RootViewDeferringInsetsHandler(ThemedReactContext context, KeyboardMovingViewView view) {
    super(WindowInsetsAnimationCompat.Callback.DISPATCH_MODE_STOP);
    mContext = context;
    mView = view;
  }

  
  @Override
  public WindowInsetsCompat onApplyWindowInsets(View v, WindowInsetsCompat insets) {
    Insets systemInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());

    mView.setContentViewInsets(systemInsets.top, systemInsets.bottom);

    return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public WindowInsetsCompat onProgress(@NonNull WindowInsetsCompat insets, @NonNull List<WindowInsetsAnimationCompat> runningAnimations) {

    WindowInsetsAnimationCompat animation = runningAnimations.get(0);


    boolean isIMEVisible = SystemUIUtils.isIMEVisible(mView);

    int imeHeight = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom;
    int navigationBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars()).bottom;

    float interpolatedFraction = isIMEVisible ? animation.getInterpolatedFraction() : 1 - animation.getInterpolatedFraction();

    imeHeight = imeHeight - (navigationBars * interpolatedFraction);
    mView.setTranslationY(-(imeHeight + (100 * interpolatedFraction)));


    return insets;
  }

}
```